# How to vertically stretch graphs with matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

With the following code, I try to plot 12 different histograms in one picture using Matplotlib.

```
for graph in range(1,13):
    name = all_results[graph-1]
    plt.subplot(4,3,graph, 
                title = name)
    plt.tight_layout()
    current_model = name
    plt.hist(all_val_accuracies[current_model],
             #range = (0.49, 0.58),
             bins = 50)
    plt.xlabel('Accuracy')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.axis([0.48, 0.58, 0, 50])
```

With this code, all histograms are plotted in one image as how I indicated it.

[However, the graphs itself are squeezed to such an extend that you cant see them anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlQxs.png)

What can I do so that these 12 histograms are plotted in one image and that each histogram can be seen clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set the size of your plots with

```
matplotlib.Figure.set_size_inches
```

To use this you will need to save the Figure object. You can include this in your code like this :

```
for graph in range(1,13):
    name = all_results[graph-1]
    fig, axs = plt.subplot(4,3,graph, 
                           title = name)
    plt.tight_layout()
    current_model = name
    plt.hist(all_val_accuracies[current_model],
             #range = (0.49, 0.58),
             bins = 50)
    fig.set_size_inches(12, 12)
    plt.xlabel('Accuracy')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.axis([0.48, 0.58, 0, 50])
```

Comment: Could you show how I can include this in my code? Im new to Matplotlib and still struggle a bit with its logic